# What is the "real" difference between val b and var b?

Tags: scala, lambda, functional-programming

What is the "real" difference between the following ?

```
val b = ( x:Double) => x * 3
var b = ( x:Double) => x * 3
```

Technically speaking, once a value is assigned to `val` , it should not be changed. However, as part of the first statement, the value of `b` could be changed to different values by passing different values of `x`.

```
scala> val b = ( x:Double) => x * 3                         
b: Double => Double = $$Lambda$1109/411756754@7a522157      

scala> b(3)                                                 
res1: Double = 9.0                                          

scala> b(4)                                                 
res2: Double = 12.0
```

What is actually happening here? Is it not that value of `b` is changing here?

Comment: No, the value of `b` is not changing. It is defined as a function. It is the same function no matter what `Double` value you pass in to it.

Comment: @jwvh, makes sense, so it is NOT the value of b which is just function definition , but the return value of function is changing here.  thanks

Answer (score 2):

`b` is a function that takes a `Double` and returns a one.

The *function itself* can't be changed, not the value it returns (functions are first class values).

If you try to do:

```
b = (x : Double) => x * 6
```

you'll get:

> error: reassignment to val

But it's possible to change the `var` one:

```
scala> b = (x : Double) => x * 7
b: Double => Double = $$Lambda$1308/1272194712@9e46050
```

But note that when you change the `var` one, you should keep its type: A function that takes a `Double` and returns a `Double`, the same if you were to change any other type like `Integer` or `Boolean`.

Answer (score 0):

In the example posted by you `b` is a function. You are passing different values to the function subsequently. Value of `b` is not changed by that.

Syntax is as follows:

[image]